# An error occurred generating a bootstrapper: Unable to begin updating resource for bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

It's a winForm application Using VS2010 with .net4.0, I get this error when publishing and have Prerequisites selected. The error goes away if I uncheck "create setup program to install preq components"

I tried copying the bootstrap packages from another machine, no luck

Answer (score 0):

I delete the prerequisite package and i've solved the problem...

Comment: This too solved my problem.  Issue is what if that Prerequisite is needed for the program to run properly?  What do you do then?  In the past this worked like a charm, but something is missing or not working correctly.  It would be nice to have a better error message too.